# how can we use apache camel's property component to read properties for plain java?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I know I can use property component to read properties for apache camel specific implementations but do camel also provide some syntax to use same syntax OR fetch properties to use for plain java code For example:

For camel specific code I can use like this :

```
camelCtx.getEndpoint(Constants.URI+"&partitioner={{partitioner.class}}&serializerClass={{serializer.class}}");
```

Now how can I use same properties for my plain java code e.g:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("metadata.broker.list",{{metadataBrokerList}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `resolovePropertyPlaceholders` method on `CamelContext` which can do this: http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#resolvePropertyPlaceholders(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thanks Claus. It saved my day. Moreover I was trying @PropertyInject annotation is it also usable in the same context or have different functionality.

Comment: Yeah @PropertyInject can work too, but then the bean must be managed by Camel or Spring or whatever ioc that may be in use. So Camel knows about the annotation on the bean and can do the injection of the value.